# How to type .reduce return value that instantiate classes?

Tags: typescript, class, reduce

I have a couple of classes, created dynamically (can be an array, object, w/e) saved in a variable and I instantiate them all using iterating it.

E.g.:

```
// This is created in another file.
import { ClassOne } from '@data/ClassOne';
import { ClassTwo } from '@data/ClassTwo';
 
export const myClasses = [
  ClassOne,
  ClassTwo,
] as const;

// Then, we iterate over it.
const classesInstances = myClasses.reduce((acc, CurClass) => {
  acc[_.camelCase(CurClass.name)] = new CurClass({
    // Some example variables just to give context.
    globalOptions,
    sharedCache,
  });
  return acc;
}, {});
```

I want to just add classes to the array/object to instantiate new classes.

My question is how can I correctly type the `classesInstances` variable so that it represents an object with the following structure:

```
classesInstances: {
  classOne: // Instance of ClassOne
  classTwo: // Instance of ClassTwo
}
```

I tried using the second argument of the `reduce` function and casting it to something with `Record<string, ???>` or `{ [key: string]: ??? }`, but I don't know what I should add to the values. Seems like a recursive problem? I'm having trouble with it.

This is as far as I've got, using an object:

```
type Instance = InstanceType<
  (typeof myClassesObj)[keyof typeof myClassesObj]
>;

type DataSourcesInstances = {
  [key in keyof typeof dataSourcesObj]: Instance;
};
```

But the `Instance` does not map correctly to the respective Class.

EDIT [22/02]:

Almost there! I was able to get the correct values but there's still a problem inside the reduce loop.

```
// First file
import { ClassOne } from '@data/ClassOne';
import { ClassTwo } from '@data/ClassTwo';

export const myClasses = {
  classOne: ClassOne,
  classTwo: ClassTwo,
};

// Second file
type ClassesInstances = {
  [key in keyof typeof myClasses]: InstanceType<
    (typeof myClasses)[key]
  >;
};

const myClassesInstances = Object.entries(myClasses).reduce(
  (acc, [key, MyClass]) => {
    // Here I'm getting: No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ClassesInstances'.
    acc[key] = new MyClass({
      context,
      cache,
    });
    return acc;
  },
  {} as ClassesInstances,
);

// myClassesInstances is correctly typed!
```

Is there a way to tell TS that the receive string is a valid key? I've tried `as keyof ClassesInstances` but the problem changes to: `Type 'ClassOne | ClassTwo' is not assignable to type 'ClassOne & ClassTwo'.`.

Comment: By dynamically you mean at run time? I dont think thats possible since typescript does type checking at compile time. You would probably have to define the type as an interface/super class or type union.

Comment: Sorry, it's not runtime, I will try to fix the question!

Comment: This is not possible as TypeScript has no way of getting the name of a class as a string literal type.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think this is a two part problem.

1. Typescript cannot guarantee that the `key` variable is a valid key of the `ClassesInstances` type.

To solve the first, you can use a type assertion to tell typescript that `key` is indeed a valid key of `ClassesInstances`

2. Typescript can't infer that `MyClass` is of type `ClassOne` or `ClassTwo`.
   To solve the second, you can specify the type of `MyClass` using a type assertion.

Putting them both together looks something like this:

```
const myClassesInstances = Object.entries(myClasses).reduce(
  (acc, [key, MyClass]) => {
    acc[key as keyof ClassesInstances] = new (MyClass as new ({
      context,
      cache,
    }) => InstanceType<typeof MyClass>)({
      context,
      cache,
    });
    return acc;
  },
  {} as ClassesInstances,
);
```

Not 100% sure if that will run right off the bat without doing a bunch of setup to get it running on my end, but I think it'll be a step in the right direction for you.